# Docky and Pidgin helper

Tags: 10.04, docky, pidgin

My pidgin helper didn't work (unread message counter didn't appear).

I'm running:

- Docky version: 2.2.0 bzr docky r1808
- ppa Pidgin 2.7.11 (libpurple 2.7.11)
- Ubuntu 10.04

Here is a stack trace

```
[Error 13:43:01.562] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Error 13:43:01.562] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 576, in msg_reply_handler
[Error 13:43:01.562] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: reply_handler(*message.get_args_list(**get_args_opts))
[Error 13:43:01.562] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 90, in list_names_handler
[Error 13:43:01.562] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: self.update_badge()
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 141, in update_badge
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: count = count + self.pidgin.iface.PurpleConversationGetData(conv, "unseen-count")
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: **keywords)
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 620, in call_blocking
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: message, timeout)
[Error 13:43:01.563] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "PurpleConversationGetData" with signature "is" on interface "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface" doesn't exist
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal:
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 214, in maybe_handle_message
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 112, in conversation_updated
[Error 13:43:06.787] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: self.update_badge()
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 141, in update_badge
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: count = count + self.pidgin.iface.PurpleConversationGetData(conv, "unseen-count")
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: **keywords)
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 620, in call_blocking
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: message, timeout)
[Error 13:43:06.788] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "PurpleConversationGetData" with signature "is" on interface "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface" doesn't exist
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal:
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 214, in maybe_handle_message
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 112, in conversation_updated
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: self.update_badge()
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/pidgin_control.py", line 141, in update_badge
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: count = count + self.pidgin.iface.PurpleConversationGetData(conv, "unseen-count")
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: **keywords)
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dbus/connection.py", line 620, in call_blocking
[Error 13:43:06.809] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: message, timeout)
[Error 13:43:06.810] [Helper] pidgin_control.py :: DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "PurpleConversationGetData" with signature "is" on interface "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface" doesn't exist
```

is there some workaround?

Comment: Mikhail, I know shorthand is fun, but this is a diverse community and you'll get better (and faster!) responses if people don't have to read your post three times to realize you mean "software." 

Is Docky running fine otherwise? It looks like there are a few Pidgin helpers out there -- can you point us to the one you installed and the process you used to install it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I didnt install any Pidgin helper, it was pre-installed with Docky. Im install docky from the repo. Can you please point me to another pidgin helper? wanna to try out something else.

Comment: So you're saying that you recently tried to use Docky's pidgin helper, which does not display recent msg counts?

Comment: yes, exactly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using docky, but I'm on 10.10 and I only have Pidgin 2.7.3. I'd consider updating Ubuntu or rolling Pidgin and Docky back to the stock install. If you're committed to getting ahead of yourself with Pidgin but sticking to the LTS Ubuntu, at least check [Docky's support network](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki#Where_Can_I_Get_Help.3F) to find out whether this is a known issue, that the Docky Pidgin helper doesn't work with 2.7.11.

Comment: gonna try this solution